# F841 still exists after adding # noqa: F841

Tags: python, python-3.6, flake8

I am adding `black` and `flake8` into my python project as hooks in git `pre-commit`, everything looks fine except the `F841` warning. I have added `# noqa: F841` to avoid warning but still get it.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue or am I doing something wrong?

I am adding two screenshots instead of paste code as it is not for code debugging.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For now (flake8<3.8), the inline noqa comment must appear on the line of the violation -- in this case it must appear directly on the assignment line

```py
std_deviation_version = report_version.get(  # noqa: F841
    "standard_deviation_data_vesrion"
)
```

---

disclaimer: I'm the current maintainer of flake8 (and pre-commit, I see you're using that too!)

I'm planning to improve this in the next release so any part of the logical line will work, but it's tricky to get correct